# Setting up Confluent Kafka Community Locally - broker container keeps exiting

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to setup Kafka locally and facing an issue. Whenever I run `docker compose up`, all containers are up correctly. After sometime, the `broker` container stops running for some reason. There is no error in the container logs.
Below is the status of all docker containers:

```
0c27a63bb0e7   confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:5.5.1            "bash -c 'echo Waiti…"    6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                                                                                                                       ksql-datagen
4e4a30204ccc   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:5.5.1              "/bin/sh"                 6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                                                                                                                       ksqldb-cli
61b86ff2a6d6   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:5.5.1           "/etc/confluent/dock…"    6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp                                                        ksqldb-server
2e022b64a760   cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen:0.3.2-5.5.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"    6 minutes ago   Exited (137) 5 minutes ago                                                                                                         connect
3c7d273683fb   confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.5.1              "/etc/confluent/dock…"    6 minutes ago   Exited (137) 5 minutes ago                                                                                                         rest-proxy
6b6d36fb9d88   confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.1         "/etc/confluent/dock…"    6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, :::8081->8081/tcp                                                        schema-registry
3bb20335ecd1   confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1                   "/etc/confluent/dock…"    6 minutes ago   Exited (137) 5 minutes ago                                                                                                         broker
7b2f922ef8ef   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1               "/etc/confluent/dock…"    6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                      2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp                                    zookeeper
```

All I want is a single node Kafka cluster with Schema Registry up and running locally. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined here? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/platform-quickstart.html#step-1-download-and-start-cp

Comment: @NicPegg - yes, followed every step in that doc.

Comment: Missed it before, looks like the ExitCode 137 is referenced. Try giving Docker more RAM. The link I referenced before recommends 6GB for mac. If using a different system, read the prerequisites section again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

137 exit code is memory related.

If all you want is Kafka and the Schema Registry, remove KSQLDB stuff, REST Proxy, and DataGen containers

I'd also suggest using a later image tag, such as 7.3.1